# ensure system connects to net in headless mode

Tags: systemd

I am trying to boot an ubuntu 22.04 server that would connect to wifi or ethernet automatically (don't have a monitor to set this up). So this is what I did:

Added a service under `/lib/systemd/system/myService.service` like so:

```
#Put me in /lib/systemd/system/
[Unit]
Description=My Net Connection
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=sm
WorkingDirectory=/home/sm
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'sudo netplan apply && sudo netplan generate'
Restart=on-failure # or always, on-abort, etc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And a netplan configuration of this kind:

```
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true   
  wifis:
    wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "<SSID>":
        password: "<PWD>"
```

Although netplan file is correct (replacing my details) it is not starting and boot.

I presume this is because the service isn't starting, but I suppose it would auto start?

Do I need to add anything?

Comment: Try running it using `systemctl start myService`. What does it say?

Comment: @balki headless means that I can not access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use NetworkManager if possible, it works very well, and has, if necessary a ncurse configuration method (trough nmtui), which is a bit simpler, if you do not have a GUI.

Normally ubuntu connects properly to the network out of the box, have you tried to reach it with ssh ?
It is possible to see it on your LAN with nmap or arp.

To check if your service is started, may be you can check with:

```
systemctl status myService
```

Maybe posting the output of thic command could be a good idea if you need further help.

If you think this is an error, you can try this command too, in order to have a little bit more information.

```
journalctl -xe
```

Netplan is a bit complicated to use, in my opinion. NetworkManager is very often configured automatically, and works out of the box in most of cases.

Oh, and did you set the rights properly on the file myService.service ?

An other solution, a little bit extreme: connect the disk of your Ubuntu to an other computer, and set the networking config via chroot. Not sure it is very efficient, but it could be a possibility.

Hope this will help you ;-)